# MongoDB updateMany with string build of substrings

Tags: mongodb, updates

I run over a problem with updating many values. I'm a newbie in terms of MongoDB. I got a task to unify dates in DB. Dates are string and now they are stored in the format yyyyMMdd. I should update it for yyyy-MM-dd. I know that storing dates as a string is far from ideal, but it is caused by implementing data standards from other companies.

I try to use .forEach() but when I was building a string inside a js function StudioT3 claimed that I should use a more modern version because it can't identify a token "{"
Then I try to use .updateMany() but it seems to not work at all. Sorry for not including any code but after a few hours I got nothing.

Summarising:
I have got a collection of Foo dates in the format "yyyyMMdd" and I need to create a query for the migration tool(in .js) which will convert it for "yyyy-MM-dd". Also, I have done a tutorial today but no-one was detailed enough to cover it.
Can you please give me a hint on how to solve it? I don't expect a full solution but I don't even know what should be the proper way to update these values.

I try with forEach(),

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:52)

> 1 |   let formatedDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;}});
    |                                                     ^
  2 |
```

```
SyntaxError: Unsyntactic continue. (3:4)

  1 | db.DummyController.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
  2 |   {if (myDoc.submissiondate.length != 6) {
> 3 |     continue;
    |     ^
  4 |   }
  5 |
```

updateMany(), and a bit with aggregation. I expect a hint on how to do it, even not a full solution.

Comment: can you show the example date of this format "yyyyMMdd"?

Comment: 20220131 its stand for yearMontDay. It's like RFC 3339 but without dashes, and time, and timezone, so it's not like rfc3339 :).

Comment: I want to be sure that multiple runs not affect DB. Actual idea is to outsource a condition validating to a filter, and handle it via .forEach(function(foo)) with js, hope that migration tool chose by rest of team can handle js functions. Can't edit my own comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$substr` to get sub string from start index and number of character
- `$concat` to concat string returned by above operation

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {}, // query
  [{
    $set: {
      date: {
        $concat: [
          { $substr: ["$date", 0, 4] },
          "-",
          { $substr: ["$date", 4, 2] },
          "-",
          { $substr: ["$date", 6, 2] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jm9aO_kbcWU)

> Note: please test this query in the development database before executing it in the production database!